# jfxDrawer making other webview pane not working

Tags: java, javafx

Basically i have a webview in which i have display a map and a jfxDrawer which is over the webview. The problem that I'm facing is that since i have implemented the drawer I can't interact with the webview(click). Could someone help me with this issue?

```
@FXML
public void showdrawer() throws IOException{
    AnchorPane trafficpane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("traffic_watch.fxml"));
    drawer.setSidePane(trafficpane);

    if(drawer.isShown())
        drawer.close();
    else
        drawer.open();
}
```

Comment: Just a guess here, but try making your `trafficpane` a `StackPane` with the nodes anchored left instead of center. Make the `WebView` fill the `StackPane`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use BorderPane as parent wrapper and put the drawer on the right side or left side after that you can hide the side when the drawer is closed

don't forget to put your webview on the center side of the BorderPane

just like this :

```
@FXML
public void showdrawer() throws IOException{
    AnchorPane trafficpane = XMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("traffic_watch.fxml"));

drawer.setSidePane(trafficpane);

    if(drawer.isShown())
    {
        drawer.close();
        borderpane.setRight(null);
    }
    else
    {
        drawer.open();
        borderpane.setRight(drawer);
    }
}
```